# Return php array to ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am running a query to database which fetch a row and i want to return it as array which can accessed as array['min'], array['max'] etc. if i echo it with specific index, it shows the value correctly in ajax but i am unable to pass complete row through it to the ajax file.

PHP file:

```
<?php 
  // Database logic here
    $calid = reset($_POST);
    require '../incs/connect.php';
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,  "SELECT * FROM calcus_sets WHERE sets_id=$calid ");
    WHILE($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo $row['min'];   break;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

JS file:

```
function DB_Fetecher(ops){
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: {ops},
          url: "calcus_es1-fetcher.php",
          success: function(res)
          {
            //  alert( res );
            alert(res);
          }
    });
}
```

This code get right value from mysql but i want to pass full row to ajax and then use each index in ajax itself to put into textboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass array by:

```
<?php 
  // Database logic here
    $calid = reset($_POST);
    require '../incs/connect.php';
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,  "SELECT * FROM calcus_sets WHERE sets_id=$calid ");

    $result = array();
    WHILE($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {

        $result[] = array( "min" => $row['min'], "max" => $row['max'] );
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

   echo json_encode( $result );
?>
```

On your js, make sure to specify `dataType:"json",`

```
function DB_Fetecher(ops){
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: {ops},
          url: "calcus_es1-fetcher.php",
          dataType:"json",
          success: function(res)
          {
            //  alert( res );
            console.log(res);
          }
    });
}
```

---

**Note:** It is advisable to use `console.log(res);` instead of `alert()` on debugging.

Comment: not working, note fetcher function runs on indexchange of select list.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you able to see a log?

Comment: Did you check on developer tools?

Comment: Great! Happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks you for the help